# How do you validate a numeric value in Katalon?

Tags: attributes, katalon-studio

I'm trying to validate a numeric value in Katalon. The Verify web UI keywords in Katalon do not work.

This is the element code:

```
<dd class="h1 no-margin" id="trans-tax1" data-value="0.085625">$0.09</dd>
```

Here's my script:

```
TestObject tax1TO = findTestObject(<path>)
def tax1Amount = "$0.09"

WebUI.verifyElementAttributeValue(tax1TO, 'translate', tax1Amount, GlobalVariable.G_Timeout_Tiny, FailureHandling.CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE)
```

When running the script, I get an error message "Object has attribute 'translate' with actual value 'true' instead of expected value".

I've also tried 'text' and 'value' instead of 'translate' in the script, but Katalon told me those attributes do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want to check for is one of the tag's attributes, probably "data-value" since you are looking at the "$0.09" which appears to be a formatted version of the data-value.

Try this:

```
TestObject tax1TO = findTestObject(<path>)
def tax1Amount = "0.085625"

WebUI.verifyElementAttributeValue(tax1TO, 'data-value', tax1Amount, GlobalVariable.G_Timeout_Tiny, FailureHandling.CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE)
```